# Create a mask matrix, where its true at max value index

Tags: numpy

Given a matrix `A = [[1, 5, 3], [4,2,6]]` I want to create a mask matrix where `1` values are at columnwise maximum value index `mask = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]`. How to do this in numpy without mutating any created arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# if A is not an np array already
A = np.array(A)

(A == np.amax(A, keepdims=True, axis=0)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar way is adding 0 to a boolean matrix to convert it to numbers:

```
mask = (A == np.amax(A,keepdims=True,axis=0)) + 0

[[0 1 0]
 [1 0 1]]
```

And this one might be faster for larger matrices:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(A)
mask[np.argmax(A,axis=0),np.arange(A.shape[1])] = 1
```